# Eclipse image shows not found image in unity launcher

Tags: 17.10, eclipse

[image]

I am a new Ubuntu user and I have installed Eclipse, various versions.
I have created a desktop short-cut, I have pasted `eclipse.png` , `eclipse.xpm` and `icon.xpm` in following folders:

```
/usr/share/pixmaps
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/
```

but nothing seems to work and I still get the above image attached in unity launcher. How to get eclipse to show correct image?

Answer (score 0):

I created an eclipse.desktop file based on gimp.desktop in **/usr/share/applications** and with the file manager I clicked on properties, browsed for the proper icon.xpm and then launched it. Funny thing is that if I use a desktop file from another location where eclipse is installed, the icon is still there :)